# A children's book series about a farm that grows massive food

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

There was a series of illustrated children's books that I was introduced to as a child in the late 1980's early 1990's.

The main character was a farmer - I can't remember the name, but I think it was Mc or Mac something. He bought his farm from a sleazy character who was trying to cheat him. The farmland was originally some kind of swampy land, but this industrious character (and his family) discovered that the land would grow plants to a massive size - radishes the size of basketballs, etc.

There were some pretty fantastic stories and adventure that the character would get into, such as one winter the weather got so cold that the wind (not the air) outside froze. They went out and cut it up and stored it in the icebox and would thaw out some of the cold breeze later in the hot summer.

The sleazy character made a constant appearance, trying to swindle this family out of the farm.

My Google-Fu seems to fail me at every turn. Do you know what this series is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*[McBroom's Wonderful One-Acre Farm](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/355281.McBroom_s_Wonderful_One_Acre_Farm)* by [Sid Fleischman](http://sidfleischman.com/booklist.html)

> When Josh McBroom learns that the eighty acres of Iowa farmland he's purchased are all stacked up on top of each other at the bottom of a muddy little pond, he thinks he's been bamboozled. But McBroom knows he's got the better of the bargain when the pond dries up to reveal an acre of soil so rich that seeds spring up into full-grown plants in no time and even nickels grow into quarters.

There were a series of small books, probably about 8 or 9, most of which are available in two collections. The above-mentioned book collects the first three stories, including *McBroom's Almanac* which is a mix of joke entries and folk remedies. Indeed, the prior owner of the farm keeps trying to swindle the farm back.

Comment: McBroom! If you knew the amount of time I've spent trying to find that name! *Thank you!*