# Trying to find a tall tale about dirt so fertile that someone steals it

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for an old tall tale - perhaps a Paul Bunyan story? - in which our hero has dirt so fertile that it will grow anything.  One of our hero's unscrupulous neighbors comes over to visit wearing spiky high-heeled shoes and leaning heavily on a cane, which annoys our hero because it puts holes in his lawn, and if he doesn't stamp the holes out quickly they'll grow larger - everything grows in this dirt.  The neighbor is later seen to be stealing the dirt - he scrapes the dirt off his shoes into a bucket, and his cane is hollow.

Comment: Duplicate confirmed by OP comment below.

Comment: You can accept RichS's answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 9):

Are you thinking of the McBroom series of stories by [Sid Fleischman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sid_Fleischman)?

The series starts with *McBroom's Wonderful One-Acre Farm*.  When Josh McBroom learns that the eighty acres of Iowa farmland he's purchased are all stacked up on top of each other at the bottom of a muddy little pond, he thinks he's been bamboozled. But McBroom knows he's got the better of the bargain when the pond dries up to reveal an acre of soil so rich that seeds spring up into full-grown plants in no time and even nickels grow into quarters.

They had planted and harvested a crop of beans within an hour, and they only had to wait three hours for a shade tree to grow. But neighbor Hector Jones was determined to swindle McBroom back out of his miraculous farm. Despite his best efforts, the family perseveres. A great story about creative problem solving and making the best of what appears to be a bad situation.

Other stories in the series.

- McBroom Tells the Truth (1966)
- McBroom and the Big Wind (1967)
- McBroom's Ear (1970/1969)
- McBroom's Ghost (1971)
- McBroom's Zoo (1971/1972)
- McBroom the Rainmaker (1973)
- McBroom Tells a Lie (1976)
- McBroom and the Beanstalk (1978)
- McBroom and the Great Race (1980)
- McBroom's Almanac (1982/1984)

In one of the stories - I forget which - McBroom's neighbor comes over often to visit. The neighbor uses strange tricks to steal the soil including the ones you mentioned where he had holes in his shoes and a hole in his cane.

All of the stories have preposterous events where Josh McBroom gets the upper hand through really unbelievable adventures.

Comment: If so, it will be a duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95577/a-childrens-book-series-about-a-farm-that-grows-massive-food/95579#95579

Comment: Indeed it is!  Thanks RichS, I'm again astonished at how fast such vague questions are answered.  This is a duplicate of 95577, but if I'd read it I doubt I'd have connected them.

Comment: The specific one I was thinking of was McBroom Tells A Lie.

Comment: @user75215 If that is the answer to your question, can you approve my response? Thanks. :-)